# Laravel @foreach - How do I display the for each value that belong to a relationship model

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Morning,

I am trying to return on an index.blade within Laravel 7

My site is set with a link to the Leagues = leagues.index blade (displays each league = at present 2)

From within leagues.index I select "go to League" = leagues.show blade (displays chosen league's menus and details)

Within the leagues.show blade there is a link to teams = teams.index blade (this at the moment displays all 64 teams from the two leagues)

What I would like to show within the teams.index blade

@foreach team that belongs to the specific league (total of 32 teams).

I have included two images of the table structures.

(1) leagues table structure

(2) my teaminfo structure.

The leagueId (1) and (2) is how I would like to define each league

**I would like to return within the teams index.blade is**

*league 1 and its 32 relevant teams displayed for the specific leagueId (1) and not display leagueId (2) teams

*league 2 and its 32 relevant teams displaying for the specific leagueId (2) and not display leagueId (1) teams

The code used at present is

**LeaguesController**

```
class LeaguesController extends Controller{

public function index()
{

    $leagues = League::all();
    return view('leagues.index', compact('leagues'));

}

   public function show($ID)
{
    $league = League::find($ID);
    return view('leagues.show')->with('league', $league);

}

   public function team()
{
    return this;hasMany(Team::class);

}}
```

**Teams Controller**

```
class TeamsController extends Controller{

public function index()
{
    $teams = Team::all();
    return view('teams.index', compact('teams'));
}

   public function show($ID)
{
    $team = Team::find($ID);
    return view('teams.show')->with('team', $team);

}
    public function leagues()
{

    return $this;belongsTo(League::class);
}}
```

**League Model**

```
class League extends Model{
use SoftDeletes;
const default = 1;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'leagues';

//public $primaryKey = 'shortName';

/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = true;

/**
 * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [
    'id',
];

/**
 * The attributes that are hidden.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [];

/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
];

/**
 * Fillable fields for a Profile.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'shortName',
    'exportId',
    'platform',
    'taggable_id',
    'taggable_type',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'id'            => 'integer',
    'name'          => 'string',
    'shortName'     => 'string',
    'exportId'      => 'string',
    'platform'      => 'string',
    'taggable_id'   => 'integer',
    'taggable_type' => 'string',
];

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function rules($id = 0, $merge = [])
{
    return array_merge(
        [
            'name'   => 'required|min:3|max:50|unique:leagues,name'.($id ? ",$id" : ''),
            'shortName'   => 'required|min:3|max:10|unique:leagues,shortName'.($id ? ",$id" : ''),
            'exportId'  => 'max:5',
            'platform' => 'required',
        ],
        $merge
    );
}

/**
 * Get the profiles for the league.
 */
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Profile');
}
public function team()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Team');
}}
```

**Team Model**

```
class Team extends Model{

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'teaminfo';
public $primaryKey = 'displayName';
/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [
    'leagueId',
];

/**
 * The attributes that are hidden.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [];


/**
 * Fillable fields for a Profile.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'teamId',
    'abbrName',
    'cityName',
    'displayName',
    'divName',
    'offScheme',
    'defScheme',
    'ovrRating',
    'injuryCount',
    'primaryColor',
    'secondaryColor',
    'userName',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'teamId'            => 'integer',
    'abbrName'          => 'string',
    'cityName'          => 'string',
    'displayName'       => 'string',
    'divName'           => 'string',
    'offScheme'         => 'string',
    'defScheme'         => 'string',
    'ovrRating'         => 'string',
    'injuryCount'       => 'string',
    'primaryColor'      => 'string',
    'secondaryColor'    => 'string',
    'userName'          => 'string',
];

    /**
 * Get the profiles for the league.
 */
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Profile');
}

    public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\League');
}}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and If you require more info and/or visual please ask..

[leagues MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G1za.jpg)

[teaminfo MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4uVZ.jpg)

Comment: You can prefilter it in your controller: `$teams = Team::where('leagueId', 1)->get()`

Comment: Hi, your code provided is works to an extent but not quite what I require. For example if I use route league/1/teams I would like all the teams with leagueId=1 to be displayed. Likewise if I use route league/2/teams I would like the teams with leagueId=2 to be displayed. Could you assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route:

```php
Route::get("/league/{league}/teams);
```

In your controller:

```php
public function index(League $league) {
    $teams = $league->team;
    return view('teams.index', compact('teams'));
}
```

Now, if you access `/league/1/teams`, laravel will find the league with id 1 and retrive all the teams belongs to that league. And yes, it works for `/league/2/teams`, whatevery you put it there, laravel will treat it as the id of leagues, if laravel can't find it, a 404 page will be shown.

Comment: I have voted your answer as the league code worked straight away with no edits. I can now display teams that correspond with each league. 

Comment: Hi again, you're code as mentioned worked perfect but it has had a knock-on effect and the show blade for the teams does show. I am getting "Trying to get property 'displayName' of non-object" I believe the issue is function show($abbrName){
    $team = Team::find($abbrName);
    return view('teams.show')->with('team', $team);
}}                    I would like to show a page of the individual team from the index blade

Comment: `find` using the id to fetch the records in the database.In this case, you may want to use `Team::where("abbr_name", $abbrName)->first()`, abbr_name is the field name in your database table, where `first()` means we only want to fetch the first record instead of an array. Change the code to suit your situation, feel free to ask me questions. However, I still recommend you to watch some tutorials. Code's Tape on the YouTube is a good place to start, that's where I first learned Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply any data filter on your controller

```
class LeagueController extends Controller
{
function index(){
    $leagues =  League::all();

    return view('league.index', compact('leagues'));
}

function view(League $league){
    $teams = $league->teams;

    return view('league.show', compact('league', 'teams'));
}
```

}

your routes would be like that:

```
Route::get('/leagues',['uses'=>'LeagueController@index', 'as'=>'leagues']);
Route::get('/leagues/{league}',['uses'=>'LeagueController@show', 'as'=>'leagues.show']);
```

and your relation

```
class League extends Model
{
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Team');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question to be more precise.I tried the code you provided by changing the models, controllers code and the routes to no success. What it brought back was all the teams within the leagues/{league}/teams and within the show blade it brought back the first from each regardless of URL. It did however separate each {league}

Comment: I have voted up your answer as the league coding worked. My votes do not show as I've a reputation below 15 